# Apache commons CSV | How can I ignore/include semicolon, comma in a field?

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to parse a log a file and store it in a CSV file. Here is a sample  line below:

```
218.1.111.50 - - [13/Mar/2005:10:36:11 -0500] "GET http://www.yahoo.com/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2898 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows 95)"
```

For this, I am using the *Apach commons CSV* library. The problem is that some fields have in the special character `;` their value, and they get interpreted as a separator.

If we look for example at the field value `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows 95)`. This single field is assigned to 3 different values because of the `;` .

[image]

I don't know the ideal method to go around this. Please see below, a snapchot of the code related to the library I use :

```
  CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                    .withHeader(HEADERS));
//
//
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                    Date date=formatter.parse(m.group("Time"));

            try {

                printer.printRecord(date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds(), m.group("NetworkSrcIpv4"),
                        m.group("ApplicationHttpStatus"),m.group("ApplicationLen"),m.group("ApplicationHttpUserAgent"),
                        m.group("ApplicationHttpQueryString"));

                printer.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
//
```

Is there any possibility of automatically ignoring the `;`, or perhaps replacing them with some values which won't affect the desired result? Is there any options I might add the my `CSVprinter` ?

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Have you tried to add quotes `""` around problematic column? Something like this: `"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows 95)"`

Comment: What does your raw CSV look like? Are the ; and , in a quoted string? (i.e. is the generated CSV at fault, or is it the way your spreadsheet is reading it?) What are you using to open the CSV - Excel?

Comment: @MichałZiober Shouldn't CSVFormat.DEFAULT do that automatically?

Comment: @Michal, I am trying to process a really large file which doesn't necessarily follow the same pattern for my regex rule. I don't think it is a practical solution (Unless of course, I need to do that programmatically, but it will take time)

Comment: Problems with logs is it can contain any char you provide as a `delimiter` so you need somehow to remove `delimiter` chars from given value.

Comment: Understood. Actually, I tried to create the csv file without using any library. And then manually replaced any problematic delimiter with a certain character, but even with that I think I missed some. Hence, I figured there a library that might already thought of this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can configure TAB as delimiter instead of using DEFAULT delimiter -

`CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.TDF.withHeader(HEADERS));`

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#TDF

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have tried this, but it didn't work. It prints the same result!

Comment: Are you opening CSV in MS EXCEL?

Comment: I am using Libre office.

Comment: Have you tried changing the delimiter while opening it in Libre Office - https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Importing_and_Exporting_CSV_Files